# Why does this code throw an error when passed to `zsh -n` but not to `zsh`?

Tags: zsh

I'm trying in this example to copy all values from one associative array to another. I'm checking my code against syntax errors using `zsh -n` but this one throws a `test:12: bar: assignment to invalid subscript range`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
typeset -A foo bar
foo=(
    Adama   "Commander"
    Tigh    "Executive Officer"
    Roslin  "President"
)
bar=()

for i in ${(k)foo}; do
    # "rubbish"
    bar[$i]=$foo[$i]
done
```

If I uncomment the `# "rubbish` line, `zsh -n` stops complaining. Is there something wrong with my code or with `zsh -n` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see what's going on by adding the debug mode (`-x`)

As the non_exec mode (`-n`) doesn't execute nothing, it doesn't execute the `typeset` so `bar` is not an "associative array", and the assignment is not valid.

I see that the presence of the "rubbish" line (or other line looking like a command) prevents the program entering in the 'for' loop.

[Zsh mailing list: zsh -n doesn't grok associate array indexes?](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2011/msg00054.html) (Jan 2011)

I tried with zsh 4.3.12 and the behaviour is more consistent, with `-n` the program never enters the 'for' loop.

For a smaller program with no loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
typeset -A bar
bar[test]=testons
echo $bar
```

zsh 4.3.10 and 4.3.12 will both execute the program the same way, but 
`zsh-4.3.10 -n` will wrongly report an error (assignment to invalid subscript range) when 
`zsh-4.3.12 -n` will not.

As a conclusion, use zsh 4.3.12 (or newer, i discover that ZSH 5 is available)
[News about zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/News/) (Including "news" from 1997!)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it gives a good view of what's going on behind the scenes. I'll upgrade my zsh version.